# I am using ListBox to get the text of the selected item, but I am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: asp.net

```
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text != null)//(error comes here)
        {
            string text = null;
            text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            ListBox2.Items.Add(text);
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(text);
```

Comment: Either `ListBox1` is null or `ListBox1.SelectedItem` is null. Which it is will determine what the error is.

Comment: Checking the .Text property and using the ToString method .. !

Answer (score 0):

The Error occur when there is no item selected :

Replace with this to verify that SelectedItem is not null:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender,EventArgs e)
     {
         if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null && ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text != null)
         {
             string text = null;
             text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
             ListBox2.Items.Add(text);
             ListBox1.Items.Remove(text);
```